# how to return false when mail transport failed in zend framework 2?

Tags: php, exception, zend-framework2, sendmail

I am trying to return `fail` message with json if the mail sending is failed, here is my code:

```
$transport = new SmtpTransport();
            $options   = new SmtpOptions(array(
                    'name'              => 'localhost',
                    'host'              => 'localhost',
                    'connection_class'  => 'login',
                    'connection_config' => array(
                            'username' => 'cscsacsac',
                            'password' => 'csdca',
                            //'ssl'=>'ssl',
                            //'port' => '465',
                    ),
            ));

            $transport->setOptions($options);
            $sent = true;
            try {

                $transport->send($mail);
            }
            catch (\Zend\Mail\Transport\Exception\DomainException $e) {
                $sent = false;
            }

            if($sent){

                echo "success";

                exit;
            }

            elseif(!$sent){

                echo "fail";

                exit;
            }
```

and here is the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '<?php echo MAIN_URL?>cases',
          data: { name: name, email: email, mobile: mobile, address: address, compliant: compliant },
          success:function(data){

            if(data =='success'){

                $('.casesMailResponse').css({'color':'#00917D'});
                $('.casesMailResponse').html('Your case has been sent successfully.');
            }

            else if(data == 'fail'){

                $('.casesMailResponse').css({'color':'#F6565B'});
                $('.casesMailResponse').html('Some errors occurred, please try again.');
            }
          },
        });
```

but in case of failure I got Internal server error due to `Incorrect authentication data`, so the failure message is not displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are catching only `Zend\Mail\Transport\Exception\DomainException`, but SMTP transport adapter can throw other exceptions too. For example in [`send`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php#L196) method it can throw `Zend\Mail\Transport\Exception\RuntimeException`.

I suggest to catch exception interface of mail package:

```php
    $sent = true;
    try {
        $transport->send($mail);
    } catch (\Zend\Mail\Transport\Exception\ExceptionInterface $e) {
        $sent = false;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you try :

```
 }
 catch (\Zend\Mail\Transport\Exception\DomainException $e) {
    $sent = false;
 } catch (Exception $e) {
    $sent = false;
}
```

Just a guess....